# InnoSetup: failed to remove temporary directory?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a function 'VerifySerialNumber' in SerialNumber.dll which depends on msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll:

```
function VerifySerialNumber(serialNumber:String):integer;
external 'VerifySerialNumber@files:SerialNumber.dll,msvcr120.dll,msvcp120.dll cdecl loadwithalteredsearchpath';
```

In [Files] section:

```
Source: "{tmp}\msvcp120.dll"; DestDir: {app}\Plugin; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{tmp}\msvcr120.dll"; DestDir: {app}\Plugin; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{tmp}\SerialNumber.dll"; DestDir: {app}\Plugin; Flags: ignoreversion
```

The problem is that the install log show "Failed to remove temporary directory: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-SKE12.tmp" when the install finised. And there are two files, the msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll file, remained in the is-SKE12.tmp folder.

Any advice?

Comment: Show us more code. How do you use the `VerifySerialNumber`? Can you share the DLLs? Some stub implementation is ok.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the DLL is not unloaded on the `DeinitializeSetup`?

Comment: @RobeN The DLL itself seems to get removed.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl but both VCR DLLs stay in TMP. Maybe these two are not unregistered at the end of Wizard/Setup? Seems that System marks them as Read-Only.